# How common is the use of the word "tee" for T-shirt in the UK or the US?

Tags: word-usage

How common is the use of the word "**[tee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tee)**" for T-shirt in the UK or the US?

I'm asking it because I saw it firstly on the site of a chain of clothing in the UK (see attached picture)

I found on [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tee) that it is in informal use (see definition No. 3). But still it's interesting to know how common it is in use. I'm afraid also to say to someone that I bought for him "tee" and he will think that I'm talking about tea...

[image]

Comment: Google Books claims 107 written instances of [*wearing a **tee** and*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wearing+a+tee+and%22), and 1170 for the same text string with [***tee-shirt***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wearing+a+tee-shirt+and%22). That's as against 12,800 with [***t-shirt***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wearing+a+t-shirt+and%22), and 14,600 with [***tshirt***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22wearing+a+tshirt+and%22), which I would think *should* be enough to answer your question. My advice: at least avoid the single-syllable version.

Comment: Labelling something as “T” (or “tee” because it ought to be a word I guess) when the thing being labelled is **a pile of shirts** is a rather special case of extreme context going beyond any normal use patterns, I think.

Comment: According to this [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=T-shirt), the "T" in t-shirt refers to the shape, which is similar to letter "T". The letter "T" is often used informally in a similar way, so that's probably the origin of the usage for a t-shirt.

Comment: In the U.S., it is roughly as common as conversations about the song "Hey There, Delilah"

Comment: It's pretty common (in the US) to see it at stores, often with the "shirt" omitted.  See [Wal-Mart](https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=tee), [Target](http://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=tee), etc.  Of course, I also found steak on sale at my local grocery last night as "STEACK 25% OFF" so....

Answer (score 30):

It's a common abbreviation term in advertising, but you generally wouldn't use it in speech the way you mention. A native speaker would most likely say "I bought you a tee shirt."

Answer (score 22):

From a British perspective "Tee" is a very American thing.

Doing a quick search on Google UK for "tee" brings up 100% US-based websites, and searching for "T-Shirt" brings up UK-based fashion shops (online & high street). Browsing a few of those sites from the home page they all have sections for "T-Shirts", but none of them have a section for "Tees". Interestingly though, searching within some of those sites for "tee" does bring up results.

Anecdotally, I have never heard anyone say "Tee" aloud, except when referring to the drink "tea".

Comment: The drink "tea" or, of course, the letter "tee".

Comment: Or a golf tee ... fore!!

Comment: From this American's perspective, "tee" is not a very American thing, no matter what this Brit might think.

Comment: I've never heard "tee" used to refer to a t-shirt. Have lived in California since 2005.

Answer (score 17):

In the US, I hear *tee* used stand-alone more often from women than men, but maybe that's because I'm more likely to be talking about clothing with women. It's not as common as t-shirt, but it's not at all strange for me to say, for example, "do you know where my purple tee is?" It's usually clear from context what I mean—for example, if I'm digging through the laundry without a shirt on while asking the previous question or if one of my kids asks about the weather and I say "I think you'll be fine in just a tee."

It's hard to get a sense of spoken patterns from a written record, but there are a lot of blog posts (like [this one](http://blissfullylively.com/boyfriend-jeans-outfit/)) and tweets (like most of [these](https://twitter.com/search?q=%22my%20favorite%20tee%22&src=typd)) that mention things like "jeans and a tee" or "my favorite tee" without using the full tee-shirt, so I don't think I'm alone in sometimes using the shorter form.

Also, in some places *tee* is countable, so it would be unlikely to be confused for the beverage—for example, I would say "I got you ***a* tee**" but "I got you ***some/a cup of* tea**". In places where the beverage is also countable, it would be more important to rely on context (especially if the tea is green or the tee is [hawt](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hawt)!).

You don't *need* to use the shorter form, though; it's always safe and acceptable to say *t-shirt* in full.

Comment: In Britain, you can *definitely* use 'a tea' to mean 'a serving/cup of tea' and similarly you could order two teas for you and your friend at a café, but this is a good answer and it doesn't really matter.

Comment: In the part of the US where I live, I hear "I got you a tea" - that is not exclusive to Britain.

Comment: @Au101 and Darren Ringer, it must have something to do with how common the beverage is. I can sort of *imagine* tea as a count noun, à la coffee, but it's definitely not a common usage in my neck of the woods. I can update the answer, however, to be more universally accurate.

Comment: There is a reference in the Amy Winehouse song "You send me flying".- "With your battered jeans and your Beastie tee".

Comment: @JavaLatte I wouldn't trust songs as good references for English. They can take poetic license and do all sorts of infuriating things to the language to make it fit the meter and melody.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes A prime example of this being those lyrics abbreviating "Beastie Boys" to "Beastie" which I'm guessing also isn't a normal thing to do.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - You've never Beastied?

Comment: I'm a US speaker, and must disagree with this answer in that I almost never hear "tee" used alone.  When I do, it seems to be from a cutesy source (think "Valley Girl" or other types prone to using frilly slang).  It is more common in print, such as store web sites, catalogs and advertisements, à la "all graphic tees 25% off."

Comment: @bubbleking are you, by chance, male and/or from the South or East Coast? In my experience US vocabulary can vary a lot by locale and is more gendered than it seems at first glance, especially in relation to highly gendered experiences like clothing and child-care, so my vocabulary as a native female AmE speaker in the Midwest and West Coast might be quite different than that of a native speaker who's male and/or who has different regional influences.

Comment: I’m midwestern and male. I’ve also lived in Kentucky and Chicago (the latter of which, while technically midwestern, isn’t really all that midwestern). I definitely agree with your assessment. My parents and extended family are from the northeast and south. You really don’t have to travel far to find AmE speakers who speak completely differently than what you’re accustomed to, yet you can meet people a thousand miles away who seem to speak exactly like you. It’s a strange phenomenon.

Answer (score 3):

The use of the word "tee" is somewhat common orally, but it generally isn't written. If you want to avoid confusion you should say "I bought you a T-shirt" or "I bought you a shirt". Either one of those should communicate what you mean to say without fear of confusing the item of clothing with the popular drink.

Comment: "Somewhat common orally" where? It seems very rare in British English. If you're going to say what is and isn't common in the language, you need to say what version of it you're talking about.

Comment: If you told me you'd bought me a shirt, then gave me a T-shirt, I'd be very confused.  In my British English, shirt on it's own always means a formal shirt.

Comment: Southeastern US here: I've only see "tee" as a standalone in advertisements and price signs: "50% off Men's solid tees". I've never heard it spoken this way.

Comment: I also need to report the opposite. A stand-alone “tee” is almost never written, and is usually only in commercial, printed material. Spoken, it’s always T-shirt (or tee-shirt, ha ha). Midwest/US.

Answer (score 2):

I,m old (ish) and British.
I have never EVER used the word "tee" to describe a T-shirt.
Does that help?

Comment: So am I, but the word is being used increasingly often in this country.

Comment: +1 Incidentally I'm young and British and would never ever use the word "tee" to describe a T-shirt. (But I might well be an exception, I don't know.)

Answer (score 0):

«I'm afraid also to say to someone that I bought for him "tee" and he will think that I'm talking about tea»

So don’t.  You are clearly a more careful and thus **clear** speaker, since you thought about this at all.

If you establish the context first you can omit the *-shirt*.

> Q: What kind of shirt should I wear?
>   A: The “T”.

or

> I packed 5 shirts for the trip: 3 “T”s, a polo, and a button-down just in case we go someplace nice for dinner.

But as a careful and clear speaker, **you** would not say something like

> I bought Dad a “T” for his birthday.

devoid of any context that you are speaking of shirts.  Unless the word “shirt” would be repeated in close proximity (like in the 2<sup>nd</sup> blockquote), there is no need to drop it from “T-shirt”.

Comment: if I asked *What kind of shirt should I wear?* and received the answer *The “T”* it would probably take me a while to twig what they meant. And then I would assume they were making a joke.

Comment: All the more reason not to use that form, except to avoid overrepitition of the word “shirt” in a short passage.  (Or make it fit in 140 chars, if that’s your thing)

Comment: +1 but note that angle brackets («...») are never used for quotation in English.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I use them specifically for quoting other SE posts, esp. when the quoted material may contain quotation marks, as is exactly the case here.

Comment: @JDługosz That's specifically what blockquote markup is for! In un-marked-up text, alternate between single and double quotes. Mary said, "John said, 'Hello.'" or Mary said, 'John said, "Hello."'